# Stuck on Formal Proofs

Tags: first-order-logic, formal-proofs

I'm trying to figure out this formal proof. This is what I have so far but I'm stuck in trying to reach the goal. I'm not sure if what I did is correct so far since I'm still trying to learn this on my own. If what I provided below is confusing, I also have a screenshot of what it looks like on the Fitch program https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd5FN.jpg Thank you so much!

Premise 1. Dodec(b) v Cube(b)

Premise 2. Small(b) v Medium(b)

Premise 3. ¬Small(b) ^ ¬Cube(b)

4. (start subproof) Small(b) ∨ Medium(b)

   5. (sub-subproof) ¬Small(b)
   6. Small(b)
   7. ⊥ (⊥ Intro 5,6)
   8. Medium(b) (⊥ Elim 7) (end subproof)

9  (start subproof) Dodec(b) v Cube(b)

10. (start sub-subproof) ¬Small(b) ∧ ¬Cube(b)
11. ¬Cube(b) (^ Elim10)
12. Dodec(b) (Ana Con 9,11)

**Goal:** Medium(b) ∧ Dodec(b)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to establish $$\{D \lor C,~ S \lor M,~ \lnot S \land \lnot C\} \vdash M \land D$$ ... is that right?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I'm not really good at formal proofs. But I'm stuck at what do do after step 12.

Comment: Break the problem into smaller steps.  First try to establish $$\{S \lor M,~ \lnot S \land \lnot C\} \vdash M$$ you'll need to use And Elimination on the second assumption, and create 2 new subproofs, one subproof will start with the premise "S" and one subproof will start with the premise "M", both of them should conclude with "M".

Comment: Having established Medium(b) (step 8) and Dodec (b) (step 12), independently of each other and using only the premises, haven't you already reached the goal?

Comment: You haven't established those things.  You've only established them in the context of the subproofs, you want to establish them outside of the context of the subproofs.  Try doing what I suggested.

Comment: You are assuming what you already have ... That makes no sense: if you already know it to be true, then there is no need to assume it.

Comment: @ashley I'll be in chat for a bit, come in and ask for me there, I'll try to help you http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics

Comment: @DanielV I don't have enough reputation to chat since I just created this account ): Is there another way to talk?

Comment: @ashley could use google hangouts...do you have a gmail address?

Comment: @ashley Ok I sent you a google hangout invite, delete your comment before a bot grabs your email

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @DanielV for your help! I really appreciate it :)
[image: Solution]

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\def\D{\operatorname{\sf Dodec}(b)}
\def\C{\operatorname{\sf Cube}(b)}
\def\S{\operatorname{\sf Small}(b)}
\def\M{\operatorname{\sf Medium}(b)}
\qquad\fitch{~~1.~~\D\vee\C\\~~2.~~\S\vee\M\\~~3.~~\neg\S\wedge\neg\C}{~~4.~~\neg\S\hspace{20ex}{\wedge}\mathsf E~3\\\fitch{~~5.~~\S}{~~6.~~\bot\hspace{25ex}\bot\mathsf I~5,4\\~~7.~~\M\hspace{15.5ex}\bot\mathsf E~6}\\\fitch{~~8.~~\M}{~~9.~~\M\hspace{16ex}\mathsf{Reit}~8}\\10.~~\M\hspace{20ex}{\vee}\mathsf E~2,5{-}7,8{-}9\\11.~~\neg\C\hspace{21ex}{\wedge}\mathsf E~3\\\fitch{12.~~\C}{13.~~\bot\hspace{25ex}\bot\mathsf I~12,11\\14.~~\D\hspace{17.5ex}\bot\mathsf E~13}\\\fitch{15.~~\D}{16.~~\D\hspace{18ex}\textsf{Reit}~15}\\17.~~\D\hspace{22ex}{\vee}\mathsf E~1,12{-}14,15{-}16\\18.~~\M\land\D\hspace{8ex}{\wedge}\mathsf I~10,17}$